# Saving issue on firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to save 40kb of json content to firestore from Google cloud function, it doesn't go through, just hangs. But if I take some content out it saves successfully. Is there any issue with Google firestore saving large amount of data in one transaction?

Will appreciate any help here!

Thanks.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you edit the question to show your code.  You might be doing something wrong.  Also be sure to include any error message from the console.

Answer (score 0):

validate your json using some tools like https://jsonlint.com

Comment: checked, json is valid. It has 98 parsed objects and 22 key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are no exceeding any of the limits shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). Also check the number of fields contained in your object as these will be indexed and due to the current functionality, there is a limit of 10k fields, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319569/some-firestore-quotas-misunderstandings?rq=1) answer for reference.